# Can I use apache http server as forwarder to Tomcat?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, load-balancing

I have a Tomcat server that listens in 8080(http), 443(https), 7443(https). Note that the connectors for 443 and 7443 use different certificates.
I am interested in using `httpd` for **load balancing**.
Is it possible to configure `httd` so that it simply forwards the requests to Tomcat without needing to install any certificate to `httpd` itself. I.e. not act as a proxy but as forwarder?
So the SSL end to end is handled by Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apache isn't capable of being a TCP load balancer; it always expects to handle HTTP requests.

For the behavior you want, take a look at HAProxy instead; it can load balance those TCP connections without being involved in the SSL layer.

Comment: Is `HAProxy` comparable to apache http performance?Also does it integrate well with Tomcat, especially if I set up cluster?

Comment: @Jim That's a bit of an apples-to-oranges comparison, especially with HAProxy working only at the TCP layer.  What kind of integration with Tomcat are you looking for?

Comment: I am interested in using Tomcat cluster and `haProxy` in front. Does it work as well as Apache with Tomcat?

Comment: @Jim Sure - since Tomcat's still terminating the SSL, it's got essentially the same options available as connecting directly to Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have a look at pound http://www.apsis.ch/pound.

This actually does https offloading as well. Setting up pound is trivial and is also very lightweight and offers good performance.

Cheers,
dexter

PS:
I thought apache had a load balancing module, but again, apache will not have the performance in load balancing as pound.